# How to know in which position a character is going to be entered?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input text as this one:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" [ngClass]="config.inputClass" 
     [(ngModel)]="field.data" step="0.01" (keypress)="checkDecimalNumbers($event, field)"
     (blur)="validateDecimalNumber(field)" [readonly]="checkReadOnly(field)" />
```

I need to know in which position a character is going to be entered, because I need to allow only the character '-' in the position 0. I have looked into all the event objects, but I haven't found anything useful. This is the typescript function, but it allows to enter the minus at any position.

```
public checkDecimalNumbers = function (ev: KeyboardEvent, field: any) {
    const key = ev.keyCode || ev.charCode;
    const keyStr = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if ((keyStr === '.' && field.data.toString().indexOf(keyStr) < 0) || (keyStr === '-' && field.data.toString().indexOf(keyStr) < 0)) {
        return;
    } else if (isNaN(Number(keyStr))) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tryed "$watch"  is like an observer?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: hii that's an angularjs solution. I need it for angular 4

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the entered character and remove if it's not '-', but at the same time add keep the first one, then replace the value with that. Something as the following:

**HTML**:

```
<input ... [(ngModel)]="input" (keyup)="format()" >
```

**Typescript**

```
format(){
  let value = this.input;
  this.input = value.substr(0, 1) + value.substr(1).replace('-','');
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfb11m?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Its not working, if you keep pressing key '-' allow to add several hyphens

Comment: oops, I forgot to save before posting, try it again, please

Comment: Add this to your input type="number" and your code stop working. And that's the problem that I have